# How to get to Workspace in DiagnosticAnalyzer and CodeFixProvider? (Roslyn)

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis, microsoft.codeanalysis

I want to check whether the configuration of a Method (Like Logger) is added to `appsettings.json`. If not, then I want to add it through Code Fix.

I am trying to access the Workspace so that I can access the documents in it. But I can't find a way to get the current workspace.

I have tried to use `AdhocWorkspace` but the projects list is empty in it

```
var solution = new AdhocWorkspace().CurrentSolution;
```

Comment: What do you mean `not working`? Any Errors? What's not working?

Comment: @KJSR The projects list is empty in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a `CodeFixProvider`, you can access the workspace from the `CodeFixContext` that is provided to the `RegisterCodeFixesAsync` method:

```
public override Task RegisterCodeFixesAsync(CodeFixContext context)
{
    var workspace = context.Document.Project.Solution.Workspace;
    //...
}
```

For a `DiagnosticAnalyzer`, it's a different story. The analyzers work with compilations, not with particular projects or documents. There is no way to reach the workspace when implementing a diagnostic analyzer, because the analyzers need to be able to run against a single compilation using only the command-line compiler.

Comment: Thanks, Do you mean there is no way to get `Workspace` in `DiagnosticAnalyzer`?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what is stated in my answer. There is no way to reach the workspace from a diagnostic analyzer (at least, using the current SDK version).

Comment: Thanks, just confused with "little bit more complicated"